# Android HttpURLConnection sending data in post request doesnt work, but javascript XMLHttpRequest does

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest, httpurlconnection

I have a server using mongodb, mongoose and node.js. 
I have implemented some GET and POST methods.

Inside a HTML website, I can post data to the server within an XMLHttpRequest as follows inside javascript:

```
function postPlantType(base64){
    var httpPost = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        path = "http://...",               // real URL taken out here
        header = ('Content-Type','application/json'),
        data = JSON.stringify({image:base64});
    httpPost.onreadystatechange = function(err) {
        if (httpPost.readyState == 4 && httpPost.status == 201){
            console.log(httpPost.responseText);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };

    path = "http://..."                   // real URL taken out here
    httpPost.open("POST", path, true);
    httpPost.send(data);
}
```

this works fine. Now I want to create an Android app, making use of such a POST request, but my Code is not working successfully. Here is my Code:

```
    private class PostNewPlantTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    String responseString = "";
    int response;
    InputStream is = null;

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls){
        DataOutputStream wr=null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);  // urls[0] is the url of the http request "http://www..."
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

            String json = "{\"image\":\"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYE...\"}";

            Log.d("json", json.toString());

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", json.getBytes().length + "");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write( json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            os.close();

            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            response = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (response >= 200 && response <=399){
                is = conn.getInputStream();
            } else {
                is = conn.getErrorStream();
            }

            // Convert the InputStream into a string
            String contentAsString = readIt(is, 200);
            responseString = contentAsString;
            conn.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            responseString = "error occured: "+e;


        } finally {
            if (is != null){
                try { is.close();} catch (Exception e) {Log.d("HTTP POST planttypes","Exception occured at closing InputStream: "+e);}
            }
        }
        Log.d("HTTP POST plants", "The response is: " + response + responseString);
        return responseString;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        // TODO: nothing(?)
        // give user feedback(?)
    }

}
```

NOTE: If I change the json String to invalid json content e.g. deleting the last "}", The response of the server is

```
400 "code":"InvalidContent","message":"Invalid JSON: Unexpected end of input"
```

So I assume the entire json string must be correct, if its unchanged.

I am hardcoding the base64encoded image String here instead of encode a real image, because of testing issues. You can see the image at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kdj62ar8/). 
If I see it correctly, its the exact same request as done from my javascript, but I get 500 internal server error. 
However, in order to get more information, here is the server function, that is called for that request url:

```
function postNewPlantType(req, res, next){
    var json = JSON.parse(req.body);
    newPlantTypeData = {
        image:json.image
    };

    var imageBuffer = decodeBase64Image(json.image);

    newPlantType = new Planttype(newPlantTypeData);

    newPlantType.save(function(err){
        if (err) return next(new    restify.InvalidArgumentError(JSON.stringify(err.errors)));
        var fileName = cfg.imageFolder + "" + newPlantType._id + '.jpeg';
        fs.writeFile(fileName, imageBuffer.data, function(error){
            if (error) log.debug(error);
            log.debug("PlantType-ImageFile successfully created on server.");
        });
        res.send(201, newPlantType);
        log.debug("PlantType successfully saved in database.");
    });
}
```

What I am wondering about is, the javascript request is working, but the android request is not. So I assume there must be a mistake in my android code. Can you help me and explain, what the error is and what I have to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of days of investigation I finally got a 201 response by changing the line

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

to

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
```

Well.. I was sending an encoded JSON and not a json itself...

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to encode it properly:

```
conn.connect();
DataOutputStream  printout = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream ());
printout.write(URLEncoder.encode(json.toString(),"UTF-8"));
printout.flush ();
printout.close ();
response = conn.getResponseCode();
...
```